# Identity insert with ODBC destination

Tags: ssis

Can one use the ODBC Destination with Identity Insert? It's easy enough to do with OLE DB, but I am either missing something or you can't do this with the ODBC Destination.

I started experimenting with the ODBC Destination as I've been reading about SQL Server is deprecating OLE DB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like OLE DB will hang around for SSIS components, but I am still a little puzzled as to using Identity Insert with ODBC. [reference](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mattm/archive/2012/01/09/sql-server-ole-db-deprecation-and-integration-services.aspx)